# TrueType font antialiased? Bitmap fonts

Tags: opengl, truetype

I'm using [this tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=13), but the font isn't antialiased. The font size is big, so it should antialiased it, but it doesn't. Do I need to enable something in openGL to make it antialiased?

Comment: As far as I know, those are NOT bitmap fonts you have in those code you posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depend on the library which you use to render the fonts. See [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/fontsurvey/) for hints how to get proper rendering quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [this system](https://threadpitch.net/mirrors/dmedia-tutorials-textrendering1/).  Works quite well when transliterated to C++.